# How to search integer fields using searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

How to make searchkick search integer fields?

Let's say i have a Book model with three properties namely name:string, author:string and pages:integer.

I want to search according to pages field. Right now if i use a query like below it works for string fields i.e name and author but it doesnt work for pages field which is of integer type.

```
Book.search(q, 
            misspellings: { below: 5 }, 
            fields: [:name, :author, :pages], 
            order: { name: 'asc' }, 
            page: params[:page], 
            per_page: 20)
```

I go to console and just searched Book.search(120, fields: [:pages]) and it returns empty result even though there are records with pages 120. Why is searchkick not searching for integer fields? I appreciate any help to this dilemma i am facing. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to search with a string value? `Book.search("120", fields: [:pages])`

Comment: yes still no effect.

Comment: my guess is the query will always be string but i need to tell searchkick that pages property is integer and should be treated like that for search. but dont know how to tell searchkick that.

Comment: What's the response you get when you call the method in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with this

In Book model

```
  def search_data
    {

      name: name,
      author: author,
      pages: pages.to_s 


    }
  end
```